# ¿Cuál es el lugar correcto para controlar los botones de un ListView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter

Estoy creando una aplicación de reproducción de música (con el único fin de aprender), cree una Activity para este fin que carga un ArraList con los datos de audio del dispositivo (almacenamiento externo), luego cargué el ListView con un adapter personalizado, al instanciar el adaptador le paso el contexto, el ArrayList, un media player y la activity. La cuestión es que manejo el MediaPlayer desde el adapter, esto lo hice así ya que no sé como identificar los botones desde el activity, por esto tuve que crear un método para recuperar el MediaPlayer para poder pausarlo o destruirlo en sus métodos correspondientes onDestroy y onPause.

La cuestión es que ahora mi código es un "caos" y me hizo pensar que está fuertemente vinculado a un único propósito, lo que me da a pensar que es una mala programación (soy estudiante). Planteo las siguientes preguntas:

**¿Es correcto trabajar con los OnClickListener desde el adaptador?**

**¿Cómo puedo identificar los botones creados programáticamente desde el activity?**

Pongo todo el código aún que es demasiado, solo por tener un contexto.

Adaptador (actualmente es un caos, necesita refactorizar pero aún no se por dónde pillarlo):

```
public class adaptador_musica_cargar extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context contexto;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<CancioneCargar> miMusica;

    private MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    private long idCancionPausada;
    private long idCancionPlayed;

    private Button botonAnteriorPlay;
    private Button botonAnteriorPause;

    //HashMap para saber el estado de las canciones (key-idCancion / map-currentPosition
    private HashMap<Long, Integer> cancionesEnMarcha = new HashMap<> ();
    private boolean segundaVez = false;
    private ProgressBarAsyncTask pb;

    //array de los botones
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Button>> listaBotones = new ArrayList<> ();

    //Constructor del adaptador
    public adaptador_musica_cargar (Context c, ArrayList<CancioneCargar> listaCanciones, MediaPlayer mp, Activity activity) {
        this.contexto = c;
        this.miMusica = listaCanciones;
        this.mediaplayer = mp;
        this.activity = activity;

        this.botonAnteriorPlay = null;
        this.botonAnteriorPause = null;
    }

    //Para coger el MediaPlayer
    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer(){
        return this.mediaplayer;
    }

    //para obtener todos los botones
    public ArrayList getButtons(){
        return this.listaBotones;
    }

    public void estadosBotones(){

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount () {
        return this.miMusica.size ();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem (int position) {
        return this.miMusica.get (position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId (int id) {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Construcción del adaptador personalizado
     */
    @Override
    public View getView (int posicion, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //cargo la lista
        View v = convertView;

        //inflo la vista que nos llega a través del layout personalizado
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from (this.contexto);
        v = li.inflate (R.layout.adaptador_musica_ejemplos, null);

        //extraigo los datos (esto es por cada iteración)
        final String tituloActual = miMusica.get (posicion).getTitulo ();
        final long idCancion = miMusica.get (posicion).getIdCancion ();
        Bitmap idMiniatura = miMusica.get (posicion).getIconoMusica ();
        String artista = miMusica.get (posicion).getArtista ();

        //Busco el textView que hay en mi layout personalizado y el VideoView
        TextView tvTituloCancion = v.findViewById (R.id.textViewTitulo);
        TextView tvSubtituloCancion = v.findViewById (R.id.textViewSubtitulo);
        ImageView ivMiniatura = v.findViewById (R.id.imageViewMiniatura);

        //cargar canción
        final String pathMusicaFileMuestra = miMusica.get (posicion).getPath ();

        //cargo el ProgressBar como final para tener acceso desde los onClick
        final ProgressBar progressBarMusicaEjemplo = v.findViewById (R.id.progressBarMusicaEjemplo);

        //almaceno todas las canciones
        cancionesEnMarcha.put (idCancion,1);


        //asigno los datos al TextView
        tvTituloCancion.setText ((artista.equals ("<unknown>")?"":artista));
        tvSubtituloCancion.setText ((tituloActual.equals ("<unknown>")?"":tituloActual));
        //cargo la imagen en el ImageView a través de setImageResource con el id pasado
        ivMiniatura.setImageBitmap (idMiniatura);

        //HashMaps para el ArrayList
        final HashMap<String,Button> botonPlay = new HashMap<> ();
        final HashMap<String,Button> botonStop = new HashMap<> ();

        final Button btResetMusica = (Button) v.findViewById (R.id.buttonReset);
        botonDissable (btResetMusica);

        final Button btStopMusica = (Button) v.findViewById (R.id.buttonPauseMusic);
        botonDissable (btStopMusica);
        botonStop.put ("stop",btStopMusica);
        listaBotones.add (botonStop);

        final Button btPlayMusica = (Button) v.findViewById (R.id.buttonPlayMusic);
        botonPlay.put ("play",btPlayMusica);
        botonEnable (btPlayMusica);
        listaBotones.add (botonPlay);

        btPlayMusica.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                 //Compruebo los botones anteriores para devolverlos a su estado original
                if(botonAnteriorPlay != null && botonAnteriorPause != null){
                    botonEnable (botonAnteriorPlay);
                    botonDissable (botonAnteriorPause);
                }

                if (idCancionPausada == idCancion) {
                    //Seteo la posición de la canción en cuestión
                    for(HashMap.Entry<Long,Integer> i : cancionesEnMarcha.entrySet ()){
                        if(idCancion == i.getKey ()){
                            mediaplayer.seekTo (i.getValue ());
                        }
                    }

                    mediaplayer.start ();
                    mediaplayer.setLooping (false);

                    botonEnable (btResetMusica);
                    botonDissable(btPlayMusica);
                    botonEnable (btStopMusica);

                    //Ejecuto tarea async para el progress bar le paso por constructor un MediaPLayer y el progressbar en los parámetros async
                    pb = new ProgressBarAsyncTask (mediaplayer);
                    pb.execute (progressBarMusicaEjemplo);

                } else {
                    //guardo el estado de la canción que se estaba reproduciendo anteirormente, solo cuando ya se cargó una vez
                    if(segundaVez) {
                        cancionesEnMarcha.put (idCancionPlayed, mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition ());
                    }

                    //Paro y vuelvo al estado Idle
                    if (mediaplayer.isPlaying ()) {
                        mediaplayer.stop ();
                        mediaplayer.reset ();
                        mediaplayer.release ();
                        mediaplayer = null;

                        if(pb != null) {
                            //cancelo el proceso del ProgressBar
                            pb.cancel (true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        mediaplayer.reset ();
                        mediaplayer.release ();
                        mediaplayer = null;
                    }

                    mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create (contexto, Uri.parse (pathMusicaFileMuestra));

                    idCancionPlayed = idCancion;
                    idCancionPausada = 0;

                    //Seteo la posición de la canción en cuestión
                    for(HashMap.Entry<Long,Integer> i : cancionesEnMarcha.entrySet ()){
                        if(idCancion == i.getKey ()){
                            mediaplayer.seekTo (i.getValue ());
                        }
                    }

                    mediaplayer.start ();
                    mediaplayer.setLooping (false);

                    botonDissable(btPlayMusica);
                    botonEnable (btStopMusica);

                    //Me guardo en una variable el botón
                    botonAnteriorPlay = btPlayMusica;
                    botonAnteriorPause = btStopMusica;
                    segundaVez = true;

                    //Ejecuto tarea async para el progress bar le paso por constructor un MediaPLayer y el progressbar
                    //new ProgressBarAsyncTask (mediaplayer).execute (progressBarMusicaEjemplo);
                     pb = new ProgressBarAsyncTask (mediaplayer);
                     pb.execute (progressBarMusicaEjemplo);

                     botonEnable (btResetMusica);
                }

                //OnCompletionListener
                mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener (){
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp) {

                        //Reestablezco la posición a 0 cuando se ha completado la canción
                        for(HashMap.Entry<Long,Integer> i : cancionesEnMarcha.entrySet ()){

                            mediaplayer.seekTo (0);

                            botonEnable (btPlayMusica);
                            botonDissable (btStopMusica);
                            botonDissable (btResetMusica);

                            cancionesEnMarcha.put(idCancion,0);

                            pb.cancel (true);
                            pb = new ProgressBarAsyncTask (mediaplayer);
                        }

                        //todo con esto se queda en loop la misma canción
                        //todo int para reproducir la siguiente canción. No se como hacerlo.
                        int random = (int) Math.random ()*cancionesEnMarcha.size ();
                        //simulo que se pulsa el botón //todo ¿Qué botón se pulsa? pues ninguno xD
                        btPlayMusica.performClick();
                        btPlayMusica.setPressed(true);
                        btPlayMusica.invalidate();
                        btPlayMusica.setPressed(false);
                        btPlayMusica.invalidate();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        btStopMusica.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                if (mediaplayer != null) {
                    if (mediaplayer.isPlaying () && idCancionPlayed == idCancion) {

                        mediaplayer.pause ();

                        idCancionPausada = idCancion;

                        cancionesEnMarcha.put (idCancion,mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition ());

                        segundaVez = true;
                    }
                }
                botonEnable (btPlayMusica);
                botonDissable (btStopMusica);

            }
        });


        /**
         * Al pulsar el botón reset
         */
        btResetMusica.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener (){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //Reseteo la canción en cuestión
                for(HashMap.Entry<Long,Integer> i : cancionesEnMarcha.entrySet ()){

                    if(idCancionPlayed == idCancion) {
                        if(mediaplayer.isPlaying ()) {
                            mediaplayer.seekTo (0);

                            botonDissable (btPlayMusica);
                            botonEnable (btStopMusica);

                            cancionesEnMarcha.put(idCancion,0);

                            mediaplayer.start ();
                            mediaplayer.setLooping (false);

                            botonEnable (btResetMusica);
                        }else{
                            cancionesEnMarcha.put(idCancion,0);
                            progressBarMusicaEjemplo.setProgress (0);

                            botonDissable (btStopMusica);
                            botonEnable (btPlayMusica);

                            botonDissable (btResetMusica);

                        }
                    } else {
                        cancionesEnMarcha.put(idCancion,0);
                        progressBarMusicaEjemplo.setProgress (0);
                        botonDissable (btResetMusica);
                    }

                    segundaVez = true;
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    /**
     * Para deshabilitar un botón
     * @param bt
     */
    public void botonDissable(Button bt){
        bt.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(contexto, R.color.colorButtonDissable), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bt.setClickable (false);
    }

    /**
     * Para habilitar un botón
     * @param bt
     */
    public void botonEnable(Button bt){
        bt.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(contexto, R.color.colorButtonEnable), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bt.setClickable (true);
    }

    /**
     * Sacar los datos de los metadatos de una canción
     */
    public ArrayList<HashMap> sacarDatosMetadatos(Context c, Uri u) {
        ArrayList<HashMap> datosCanciones = new ArrayList<> ();
        HashMap<String,String> datosCancion = new HashMap<> ();

        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever ();
        mmr.setDataSource (c, u);

        String nombreAlbum = mmr.extractMetadata (MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
        String tituloCancion = mmr.extractMetadata (MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

        datosCancion.put ("titulo",nombreAlbum);
        datosCancion.put ("cancion",tituloCancion);

        datosCanciones.add (datosCancion);

        return datosCanciones;
    }
}
```

Activity que contiene el ListView:

```
public class activity_cargar_canciones_archivos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int ID_PERMISOS_READ_EXTERNAL = 9999;

    private ListView lvCargarMusica;
    private ArrayList<CancioneCargar> cancionesAlmacenadas = new ArrayList<>();
    private Funcionalidad funcCargarArchivos;
    private adaptador_musica_cargar amc;
    private MediaPlayer mpCargar;

    private boolean pausado = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_cargar_canciones_archivos);

        lvCargarMusica = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listViewCargarMusica);
        funcCargarArchivos = new Funcionalidad (this, this);
        mpCargar = new MediaPlayer ();


        //pedir permisos
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission (this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //compruebo almacenamiento externo disponible
            if (isExternalStorageReadable ()) {
                // cargo el array
                cargarArchivosMusica (this);
                //cargo el adaptador
                amc = new adaptador_musica_cargar (this, cancionesAlmacenadas, mpCargar, this);
                //añado el adaptador al listView
                lvCargarMusica.setAdapter (amc);

            } else {
                funcCargarArchivos.dialogoPermisos ("Error con almacenamiento extero.","Su almacenamiento externo no está preparado. Si tiene SDCARD compruebe que está bien insertada");
            }
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions (this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, ID_PERMISOS_READ_EXTERNAL);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Respuesta a la petición de permisos de lectura
     *
     */
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResult) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResult);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case (ID_PERMISOS_READ_EXTERNAL):
                //En caso de que se le concedan los permisos se ejecutará el método para buscar el vídeo y cargarlo
                if (grantResult[0] == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    // cargo el array
                    cargarArchivosMusica (this);
                    //cargo el adaptador
                    amc = new adaptador_musica_cargar (this, cancionesAlmacenadas, mpCargar, this);
                    //añado el adaptador al listView
                    lvCargarMusica.setAdapter (amc);

                } else {
                    funcCargarArchivos.dialogoPermisos ("Error con los permisos","Debes de conceder los permisos para poder buscar un archivo.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Método para cargar los archivos de música en el Array
     */
    private void cargarArchivosMusica(Context contexto){

        ContentResolver cancionesResolver = getContentResolver ();
        Uri cancionUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cancionCursor  = cancionesResolver.query (cancionUri,null,null,null);
        String uri;

        if(cancionCursor != null && cancionCursor.moveToFirst ()){
            //extraigo las columnas
            int tituloColumna = cancionCursor.getColumnIndex (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumna = cancionCursor.getColumnIndex (MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistaColumna = cancionCursor.getColumnIndex (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

            do{
                uri = cancionUri.toString () + "/" + cancionCursor.getLong (idColumna);
                //voy sacando los datos del cursos y lo almaceno en el Array
                long id = cancionCursor.getLong (idColumna);
                String titulo = cancionCursor.getString (tituloColumna);
                String artista = cancionCursor.getString (artistaColumna);

                //Saco la imagen del album de los metadatos, le pongo uno por defecto
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (getResources (),R.drawable.icono_musica_miniatura);
                MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mmr.setDataSource(contexto,Uri.parse (uri));
                byte[] artBytes =  mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
                if(artBytes!=null) {
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(artBytes, 0, artBytes.length);
                }

                //todo

                cancionesAlmacenadas.add (new CancioneCargar (id,titulo,artista,uri,bm));

            }while(cancionCursor.moveToNext ());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Comprobar que el almacenamiento externa está montado y listo para leer
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause ();
        //busco el MediaPlayer en cuestión
        mpCargar = amc.getMediaPlayer ();

        if(mpCargar.isPlaying ()) {
            //lo pauso
            mpCargar.pause ();
            pausado = true;
        }

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Button>> listaBotones = amc.getButtons ();

        for(int i = 0; i < listaBotones.size ();i++){
            HashMap<String,Button> boton = listaBotones.get (i);
            for(HashMap.Entry<String,Button> z : boton.entrySet()){
                if(z.getKey ().equals ("play")){
                    amc.botonEnable (z.getValue ());
                } else if(z.getKey ().equals ("stop")) {
                    amc.botonDissable (z.getValue ());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume ();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy ();
        mpCargar = amc.getMediaPlayer ();
        if(mpCargar != null){
            mpCargar.release ();
            mpCargar = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Objeto CancioneCargar

```
package com.foc.reproductorvideo.music.musica_cargar;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class CancioneCargar {

    private long id;
    private String titulo;
    private String artista;
    private String uriCancion;
    private Bitmap iconoMusica;


    public CancioneCargar(long songID, String songTitle, String songArtist,String path,Bitmap iconoMusica) {
        this.id=songID;
        this.titulo=songTitle;
        this.artista=songArtist;
        this.iconoMusica = iconoMusica;
        this.uriCancion = path;
    }

    public long getIdCancion(){return this.id;}
    public String getTitulo(){return this.titulo;}
    public String getArtista(){return this.artista;}
    public String getPath(){return this.uriCancion;}
    public Bitmap getIconoMusica(){ return this.iconoMusica; }

}
```

XML LAyout del Activity con el ListView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".video.reproductor_video_ejemplo"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/imagen_fondo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                style="@style/subtitulo"
                android:text="@string/titulo_video_msuica" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewCargarMusica"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML del layout del adaptador:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewMiniatura"
            style="@style/imageView_portrait"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/video_player" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitulo"
            style="@style/titulo_grupos"
            android:text="Titulo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSubtitulo"
            style="@style/subtitulo_canciones"
            android:text="Subtitulo"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPlayMusic"
                    style="@style/botones_musica_play"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPauseMusic"
                    style="@style/botones_musica_pause"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
                    style="@style/botones_musica_pause"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="R" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBarMusicaEjemplo"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progress="0"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Lo mejor que te puedo recomendar es que crees un control (un custom view) por ejemplo, una clase que herede de ViewGroup, como, LinearLayout, FrameLayout o el que mejor se adapte a tu necesidad. La idea es que infles tu Layout personalizado del reproductor y manejes todas las acciones y eventos que pertenecen a esa vista personalizada ahí. Así solo tendrías que controlar esos eventos en el adaptador. Digamos que creaste MyMediaPlayer. En el adaptador solo tendrías que pasarle que audio reproducir, pausar manualmente, obviamente debes crear tus propios métodos que controlen esas acciones

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, con lo que comentas y la respuesta que me dio Erick Silva me pondré manos a la obra a refactorizar y aprender de una vez a mantener un código decente y no la basura a la que estoy mal acostumbrado.  ¿Recomendarías el uso de RecyclerView en ver de un ListView?

Comment: Si, te recomiendo 100% el uso del RecyclerView sobre ListView. Normalmente, ListView se utiliza cuando tienes vistas simples, como mostrar texto. RecyclerView es más flexible y customizable, además de que tiene mejor rendimiento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramon tardaria mucho en refactorizar todo el codigo para que funcione como quieres, te intentaré responder de forma que entiendas el concepto y lo apliques de la mejor forma en tu codigo.

Primero voy a dividir tu problema en 3 problemas comunes para que podamos aplicar soluciones que nos sirvan en muchos otros problemas similares.

**1- ViewHolder con varios botones**

Cuando un item de una lista tiene varios botones, o acciones mas complejas que simplemente seleccionar todo el item; lo mejor es crear una interfaz que nos sirva para delegar esas acciones en el Activity o Fragment que tiene ese adapter.

```
public interface MiAdapterCallback {
   public void play(index int);
   public void stop(index int);
   public void pause(index int);
}

public class MiAdapter{
   public MiAdapterCallback miCallback = null;

   public class MiViewHolder{

     void onClickPlay(indice int){
       if (miCallback != null) miCallback.play(indice)
     }
     void onClickPause(indice int){
       if (miCallback != null) miCallback.pause(indice)
     }
     void onClickStop(indice int){
       if (miCallback != null) miCallback.stop(indice)
     }
   }
}

Public class MiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implemet MiAdapterCallback{
   public void play(index int){
     //Aca el codigo para hacerle play al mediaplayer
   }

   public void stop(index int){
     //Aca el stop del mediaplayer
   }
   public void pause(index int){
     //Si adivinaste, el codigo para la pausa
   }
}
```

**2- El Item debe guardar su estado**

Este problema se puede presentar por ejemplo si tenes una lista con checks para seleccionarse o en este caso imagino que tenes que guardar los items que estan en play, pausa y seguramente el segundo en donde se detuvo en caso de estar en pausa.
Para resolver esto deberas agregar alguna variable o variables de estado dentro del modelo que estas usando para el array en este caso dentro de la clase `CancioneCargar`

```
public class CancioneCargar {
  private long id;
  private String titulo;
  private String artista;
  private String uriCancion;
  private Bitmap iconoMusica;

  //Aca agrego una variable de estado que sirva para reconstruir el item y no se pierda su estado
  public long segundosReproducidos;
  public bool algunOtroEstado; 
}

Public class MiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implemet MiAdapterCallback{

  public void pause(index int){
    miMusica.get(index).segundosReproducidos = 30; //Obviamente poner el tiempo correspondiente segun el MediaPlayer
  }
}
```

**3- Responsabilidades!**

En la programacion cada clase debe ser responsable de hacer algunas cosas y delegar aquellas cosas que no le corresponden. En este caso estas ejecutando el MediaPlayer desde el item de un adapter. El adapter es solo responsable de presentar la lista y el item apenas es responsable de mostrarse a si mismo y atrapar sus propios clicks. A travez de la interfaz delegamos el comportamiento del MediaPlayer al Activity, de esta forma, en un solo lugar controlas el play y pausa de todos los audios, no tenes que pedirle a todos los items que pausen la reproduccion, siempre tenes un solo media player y te evitas errores.

Comment: Muchas gracias por una respuesta tan elaborada, ni mucho menos pedía que me refactorizasen el código, si no más bien unos consejos como me mencionas, yo mismo veía que estaba todo muy mal y era un caos, como bien comentas el Adapter tiene una función concreta y me parecía raro tener que controlarlo todo desde ahí. Mil gracias, esto me ayudará mucho, estudio el grado superior de DAM a distancia y no nos enseñan a tener un código ordenado, y a penas veo más código que aquel que cuelga el tutor. Me pondré en seguida manos a la obra para aplicar los consejos que mencionas. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Ramón que bueno que te intereses por tener el codigo ordenado, en la medida que los proyectos crecen es vital que todo tenga un sentido, que sea legible y que quede muy claro que hace cada cosa. Exitos en tus estudios